# How to connect my mobile app (written in lua) and my server (written in node.js)?

Tags: node.js, lua

I am new to lua and node js and I am trying to connect the mobile app that I'm working on to the server. The problem is it connects to the server but the data that I am trying to pass gets lost or it doesn't reach the server.
Any ideas on what's wrong with what I'm doing?

[this is my lua code to connect to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNXrA.png)

```
local function store ()

    local headers = {}

    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"

    local body = "fname="..fname
    local params = {}

    params.headers = headers
    params.body = body

    print(body)
    print(headers)
    print(params.body)
    print(params.headers)

    network.request( "http://192.168.56.2:8888", "POST", networkListener, params )

end



local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!")
    else
        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
        local serializedString = json.decode( event.response )

                            print(serializedString)

        --data = json.decode(serializedString)
        --print(serializedString.student[1])

    end
end
```

`

[This is the code for the simple server I am trying to send a request to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huXkY.png)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var morgan = require('morgan');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var parser = require('luaparse');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.listen(8888,function() {console.log('Server Running!');});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', consolidate.nunjucks);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var fname = req.fname;
    var lname = req.body.lastname;

    console.log("it went in");
    console.log(req.body.fname);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.header);
    console.log("nahuman");


  res.render('index.html');
 });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Please include code in your question in the place of image links, if possible.

Comment: I edited my question and include parts of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is Ok, except that it seems your network listener `networkListener()` is declared **after** your `store()` function. Lua  cannot access stuff declared **after** what you are executing, *unless* it is forward declared. So, lua does not find the listener and it does not get called, even if there was an error. This function should be declared before your `store()` function, so that it can access it, like this:

```
local function networkListener(event)
    ...
end

local function store()
    ...
end
```

That, or you could forward declare it, sort of like this:

```
local networkListener = nil -- This forward declaration

local function store()
   ...
end

networkListener = function()
    ...
end
```

[Here is more info about lua forward declaration](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.2.html). I know this is the case since you provided us with a screenshot of your actual code order. You can always use a debugger to see if everything is working OK after you try the solution. I recommend the IDE [zerobrane studio](https://studio.zerobrane.com/).